# Cannot insert combobox in column. Extjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs4

Cannot insert combobox in column. I use other methods but it don't work for me

This is link to full code [full code](http://jsfiddle.net/uNggs/)

This is column:

```
cols.push(Ext.create ('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
    text: 'Article',
    dataIndex: 'subOperationItemArticle',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store:  me.store,
        displayField: 'subOperationItemArticle',
        valueField: 'subOperationItemArticle'
    },
    renderer: function(val) {
        index =  me.store.findExact('subOperationItemArticle',val); 
        if (index != -1) {
            rs = me.store.getAt(index).data; 
            return rs.display; 
        }
    }
}));
```

Comment: `editor` config works only with `Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing` or `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` plugins. I can not see plugin setup in your complete code. If you want to use combobox for editing values in grid, you need to setup edit plugin firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Skirtal `component-column` and obtained desired result. Here is a column example that will render a gender selection combo box.
Link is http://skirtlesden.com/ux/component-column

```
{
                text : 'test',
                width : 200,
                xtype : 'componentcolumn',
                renderer : function() {
                    return {itemId : 'siteusergender',
                        fieldLabel : 'Gender',
                        xtype : 'combo',
                        displayField : 'name',
                        valueField : 'id',
                        editable : false,
                        name : 'gender',
                        hiddenName : 'gender',
                        store : Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                            fields : ['name', 'id'],
                            data : [{
                                name : 'Male',
                                id : '1'
                            }, {
                                name : 'Female',
                                id : '2'
                            }]
                        })}
                }
            }
```